# How to make menu anchors worked in multiple pages Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.7

I added anchors to some of my menus in the Main menu. ***For example: Main Menu: Home |  Product | About Us | Contact Us***. In menus **Product** and **About Us** I made external link menu and add #div id of the section that is the content. I added and smooth scroll to menu and submenus. Everything in Homepage works fine, but when go to menu **Contact Us** and click on menu **About Us** nothing happens. Just put anchor behind the URL in the browser. ***For Example: http://domain.com/contact_us#about_us***. Hot to make it work when click on menu with anchor to go to Homepage and scroll to section of the anchor?

Thank you in advice!
Best Regards,
George!

Comment: Can you post the actual URL?

Comment: This is the project - http://www.ruhouse.eu/  The project is on Bulgarian language and the second, 3-th and forth menus are with anchors. Link to Homepage is working in inside pages.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to resolve my problem. First must made second main menu, for example: ***Main Menu Inside*** with all elements from the **Main menu**. After that put in front of anchor "/" to use whole domain + anchor. For example: ***/#about_us*** . After that it must remove module menu for **Main Menu** from pages that it will use second **Main Menu Inside** and in module menu **Main Menu Inside** must add menus that will appear in new second Main menu. Now for me everything works fine.